# Can't import/update product, keep getting this "product_type" error

Tags: error, import, product-type

[image][image: error message]
I have some issues with importing new product and updating.

Comment: Which version of Magento is this?

Comment: ValidatorInterface::ERROR_INVALID_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ValidatorInterface::ERROR_INVALID_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE error.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I added a screenshot of the csv file

Comment: first of all you have to change colomn name  "type_product" => "product_type"  &   "simpel" => "simple"

Comment: now after above change you have issue , then go to magento admin and open : admin > system > import > select entity type = "products"  and download sample file and show which kind of data you have to set in your file.

Comment: Yes sir ,but ,before yesterday i can not add comment.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works!